# Maven Spring Jetty Server can't find anything

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-jetty-plugin

Been trying for weeks just trying to get a Spring MVC App up and running and using a Jetty server. The problem is that even though it can find the WebApplicationInitializers and the logs don't throw up anything suspicious it gives me a Error 404 Not Found. It's as if it can't or won't listen to the Controller I've defined. This is a no XML pure java config Spring MVC webapp

I'm using these guides:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/

and

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-4-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/

My POM configures jetty-maven-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </webApp>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
        <wtpContextName></wtpContextName>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The following is my directory structure:

[image]

The Scan file just tells Spring to scan everything in co.uk.naz.cv so it'll pick up the annotations in the subpackages.

Everything else is typical configuration:

My WebConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig
{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/core/js/", "/resources/core/css/", "/resources/core/css/images")
        .setCachePeriod(3600)
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

My RootConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = { @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class) })
public class RootConfig
{
    //Class is intentionally left empty
}
```

WebAppInitialiser:

```
public class WebAppInitialiser extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() { return new String[] { "/" }; }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() { return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class }; }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() { return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class }; }
}
```

and the simple controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() { return "index"; };
}
```

This has been a nightmare and the closest I've gotten it's getting a directory listing which would allow me to navigate to a html file.

Hopefully this is an easy fix but I can't for the life of me see what's wrong here. All I want is for this WebApp to return the index.jsp file. I've double checked all the paths and I'm sure they are correct.

For completion here is the log:

```
[INFO] Logging initialized @1353ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src/main/webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] nonBlocking:false
[INFO] Classes = /home/naz/Eclipse/Projects/cv/target/classes
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: cv Maven Webapp
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = /home/naz/Eclipse/Projects/cv/target/tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = null
[INFO] Webapp directory = /home/naz/Eclipse/Projects/cv/src/main/webapp
[INFO] jetty-9.4.11.v20180605; built: 2018-06-05T18:24:03.829Z; git: d5fc0523cfa96bfebfbda19606cad384d772f04c; jvm 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11
[INFO] Scanning elapsed time=148ms
[INFO] 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
[INFO] DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
[INFO] No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
[INFO] node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
[INFO] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[INFO] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2a22ad2b{/,file:///home/naz/Eclipse/Projects/cv/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///home/naz/Eclipse/Projects/cv/src/main/webapp/}
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@33f2cfda{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started @2681ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Comment: The current main version of Spring is 5.0 (with 4.3 in widespread use); a Spring 3 tutorial is completely obsolete. What you're trying to do is almost certainly going to be much easier with Spring Boot, which is the modern way to write Spring applications (very specifically including not having to manually handle Web containers).

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. One of the tutorials is Spring 4, I'm just looking at the Spring 3 tutorial for maven specifics + plus using a Spring 4 book as a reference. I've done Spring Boot WebApps before but want to configure this from scratch.

Comment: Good luck. There's a reason people don't do that anymore!